# Split files stored in a variable

Tags: java, split

I'm working with ETL, where I'm storing all file names in a context variable like this

```
context.variablename = context.variablename+input_column
```

And output of this variable come like this:

```
context.variablename = 01-01-2015.csv.good, 01-02-2015.csv.bad, 01-03-2015.csv.good, 01-04-2015.csv.bad
```

In input_column I have list of files like this

> 01-01-2015.csv.good
>   01-02-2015.csv.bad
>   01-03-2015.csv.good
>   01-04-2015.csv.bad

I want to split file names into two variables according to their extensions.

As a result, `context.goodfilevariable` will store only these files:

> 01-03-2015.csv.good
>   01-01-2015.csv.good

While `context.badfilevariable` will store only these files:

> 01-02-2015.csv.bad
>   01-04-2015.csv.bad

How can I achieve this with Java?

Comment: What have you coded so far?

Comment: In ETL I have just this, context.variablename = context.variablename+input_column And when I print this variable I get the out put like this "context.variablename = 01-01-2015.csv.good, 01-02-2015.csv.bad, 01-03-2015.csv.good, 01-04-2015.csv.bad"

Comment: So you are using some kind of ETL tool? Do you not have any java code written?

Comment: Nope Josh , that's all I have!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more helpful data structure than a `String` for storing multiple `Object`s (`String`s in your case) is an `ArrayList`. These can store any number of separate `Object`s of the same class, stack memory providing. You could write the following:

```
// Reading the input
BufferedReader reader = ... // And initialize the reader
ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
while (reader.hasNextLine())
    input.add(reader.readLine());

// Storing the input
ArrayList<String> good = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> bad = new ArrayList();
for (String s : input) {
    sections = s.split(".");
    if (sections[sections.length - 1].equals("good"))
        good.add(s);
    else if (sections[sections.length - 1].equals("bad"))
        bad.add(s);
    else
        throw new IOException("Invalid filename.");
}

// Do whatever you want with the good and bad ArrayLists after this.
// If you want arrays, you can use ArrayList's toArray() method.
```

Some things to note:

- We initialize an `ArrayList` with a storage class type, `String` in this case, and put the class name in the diamond operator, `<` and `>`.
- The second, empty diamond in `new ArrayList<>()` is due to type inference. This feature only works with Java 8, so if you're using an older version, you'll need to put the class name in the operator.
- The `for (String s : input)` is different from the standard `for` loop. This is called the enhanced for loop, which iterates over all the items of an array or class that implements Iterable.
- The `String.split(String)` method splits a `String` (as is evident by the name) by the delimiter given.

Comment: So can I use my context.variable instead of input at initializing array list ?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't matter what variable you use.

Comment: @roy Also, if you find anything in a post helpful, please feel free to vote it up. If it's still confusing, please ask questions. You might have already known about upvoting, but if you didn't, take a look at the [site tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).